# Wick Theorem: number of contractions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, wick-theorem

I have to prove that the number of contractions in Wick's Theorem
is equal to:

$$\frac{n!}{(n/2)! \ 2^{n/2}} \ \ \ where \ \ n \ \ is \ even$$

I don't know how to start, if someone can help.

Comment: Well, as a start can you confirm it for $n$ small?

Comment: yes, it is ok for n=6, i got 15 contractions which is correct

Answer (score 1):

Since $n$ is even, I prefer to work with $2n$ instead. Take the correlator $\langle \phi_1 \cdots \phi_{2n}\rangle$. Starts with $\phi_1$: it has exactly $2n-1$ contractions; once all the $\phi_1$ contractions have been taken care, consider $\phi_2$: it has $(2n-3)$ contractions; in general $\phi_k$ has $(2n-k)$ contractions. Hence, the total number of contractions is:
$$\# = (2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots (3)\cdot(1)$$
But this is equal to your equation as:
$$ \frac{(2n)!}{((2n)/2)!\,\,\,2^{(2n)/2}} = \frac{(2n)\cdot(2n-1)\cdots (2)\cdot(1)}{(2n)\cdot(2n-2)\cdots(4)\cdot(2)} = \#$$